# Download JSON in Informatica Application Integration

Tags: web-services, informatica

I am new to and ICAI, and i have a requirement

- a. create a service
- b. the user will upload a json file using this
  webservice
- c. the json file will be downloaded and saved locally.

The solution path i was taking is:

create a process which will accept 2 inputs (some generic text and the json file)

[image]

which generated the below url

[image]

I tested the same in POSTMAN and it is working fine, but i am not able to download the json into informatica server on any location,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to use a `FileWriter` Service. Check out [this knowledgebase article](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/564228) for details.

Comment: ooh okay.. got it.. 
thank you very much.. it worked.

Comment: Great! Consider marking this answer as correct for future reference. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Final solution based on the feedback from Maciejg

Steps taken:

1. create a filewriter app connection and set it up only for
   "eventtarget"
2. create a process
3. in start - create a input field of type - attachment

[image]

4. in start - create a temp field of type - filewriter connection

[image]

5. add a assignment task
6. in assignment task add a filed temp->content format of type content
   -> attachment
7. in the same assignment task add another field temp->file name of
   type formula

Above steps are enough to save the uploaded file, if required, other steps (check file type, authentication etc) can be added.

[image]

[image]